# How do you get a wedding dress in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do you get a wedding dress in Skyrim? It is possible. I'm looking at the guidebook but cannot find out how to do it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there any purpose or goal you're trying to complete that requires the wedding dress?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [Wikia page for the Wedding Dress](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Wedding_Dress_(Skyrim)):

> **Location:**
>
> - It can be looted from the dead body of Vittoria Vici during the [Dark Brotherhood](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Brotherhood_(Skyrim)) quest [Bound Until Death](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bound_Until_Death).
> - It can also be found in the Hall of the Dead in [Solitude](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Solitude_(Skyrim)), after completing the quest, in a coffin. The coffin also holds a wedding ring, headdress, and sandals.